# AndroidアプリにAdMobを追加すると表示キーボードが変わってしまう

Tags: android, java, admob

android studioで計算アプリを制作しています。
計算自体は問題なくできるのですが、edittext欄に値を入力するためのキーボードの挙動がおかしいので困っています。
AdMobを挿入する前は問題なかったのですが、挿入後に挙動がおかしくなりました。

**挿入前**
1. 数値の入力をした後、キーボードの矢印ボタンを押下すると、次の入力欄にカーソルが移ります。
2. 最後の入力項目の欄にカーソルが移ると、キーボードの矢印ボタンがチェックマークに変わる。

**挿入後**
1. 数値の入力をした後、キーボードの矢印ボタンを押下すると、次の入力欄にカーソルが移ります。（問題なし）
2. 最後の入力項目の欄にカーソルが移ってもキーボードの矢印ボタンがチェックマークに変わらない。
3. その矢印ボタンを押下すると、画像のようにアルファベットのキーボードが表示されてしまう。

AdMobを挿入する前のキーボードの状態にしたいです。どなたか分かる方ご教示お願い致します。

**AdMob挿入前の画像**
[image: AdMob挿入前]

**AdMob挿入後の画像1**
[image: AdMob挿入後1]

**AdMob挿入後の画像2**
[image: AdMob挿入後2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決方法が見つかりましたので、自分で回答します。

質問に対する答えとしては少しズレてますが、自分としてはこの方法で解決したと考えました。

キーボードに表示される矢印ボタンをチェックマークに変える方法の代わりに画面のキーボード以外の部分をタップすればキーボードが消える仕様にしました。

キーボード以外の部分をタップすることで、layoutviewにフォーカスする方法を取りました。
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

java

```
// キーボード表示を制御するためのオブジェクト
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
// 背景のレイアウト
private LinearLayout mainLayout;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cal_bending_moment);

        // キーボード表示を制御するためのオブジェクト
        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout3);
.....
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // キーボードを隠す
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        // 背景にフォーカスを移す
        mainLayout.requestFocus();

        return true;
    }
```